# Android Force Location of Apps

Tags: android

I work in QA for an company that helps market applications. Currently I have been tasked to ensure location dependent apps function if correctly (ie if im in russia the app displays the russian content and if i change to us the app updates to the us content)

I have tried numerous items to accomplish this but get no where.

What i have tried:

*Proxy.*  Setting this up via wifi to several locations. Both the app and the device still show my current location.
*Apps*: I have tried all of the following apps and they all give the same result as above.
Fake Location
AutoProxy
Fake GPS

I have enabled developer mode on the devices, and have ensured that "Mock Locations" is checked.

Use case 1:
A developer whats us to test his app which is only available in england. Google Play still sees me in US

Use case 2:
A developer releases a game where the background changes based on your location if i cant force the location change  I cant verify this feature works.

Im guessing the fails so far are due to the fact that the location being called in our test apps is network location not GPS?

Any help would be awesome. Even if you could just point me in a direction.

Thank you  Greatly

J

**Update:**
Ok, Thanks to the answers about google play and mock locations. So with those in mind lets think about it from another perspective.  If the app is not calling for mock location, Is there anyway to force a mock location override?  im trying to cover all the bases here, One app for sure does not use this method, so I still need to find a way around.

depending on how they are calling for the location, I would think (remember im knew here) that using a proxy would work, however as stated above, i'm not getting anywhere there either.  Did try a few free proxy's from hidemyass but even the browser wouldn't work with them.

Comment: Case 1: Faking the GPS or network location won't help. If you need to buy an App from Play that's only available in the UK region, you'll need a Play account that's in that region. (Or the developer who wants his app tested can just send the APK to you...)

Comment: Matt Gibson, Thank you for the work around. Ill look into that. as for the obvious solution (Or the developer who wants his app tested can just send the APK to you...) lol I wish it was always that way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, network location does not get faked by mock location providers.  I don't know why not, but it only fakes GPS.  In addition, your app has to request the MOCK permission to get it.  If it doesn't have this permission, setting a mock location will not actually fake anything to the app.  This is for security purposes, so a malicious app can't start broadcasting the wrong location to the phone.